# Asp.net drop down list issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, dropdown

I have a dropdownlist that gets set in a separate function. So first when the page loads It will get a value from SQL database and passes that value to a method that populates the dropdownlist. The populate method inserts item to the drop down based on the parameter it receives.

Also I have a block of code in the page load event like the following

```
if (!IsPostBack) 
{
    // CALL THE POPULATE FUNCTION
}
```

The above block will only populate the dropdown the first time the page is loaded. I don't want it to repopulate on post backs from a button

There is a search button and I have to put an ID and click search. When I click search, the drop down will retain its items but it will select the first item. Before I click search sometimes I change the drop down selection and I would like it to stay that way after clicking search but it always goes back to the first item.

Basically what I have is the following:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Search" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

## **Code behind:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
        DropDownList1.Items.Clear();
        string test = "17/FO";
        Populate(test);
    }
}

protected void Populate(string t)
{
    string t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6, t7, t8, t9, t10,t11,t12;
    if (t.Contains("/FI"))
    {
        t1 = (int.Parse(t.Substring(0, 2)) - 1).ToString() + "/FI";
        t2 = (int.Parse(t.Substring(0, 2)) - 1).ToString() + "/SE";
        t3 = (int.Parse(t.Substring(0, 2)) - 1).ToString() + "/TH";
        t4 = (int.Parse(t.Substring(0, 2)) - 1).ToString() + "/FO";
        t5 = t.Substring(0, 2) + "/FI";
        t6 = t.Substring(0, 2) + "/SE";
        t7 = t.Substring(0, 2) + "/TH";
        t8 = t.Substring(0, 2) + "/FO";
        t9 = (int.Parse(t.Substring(0, 2)) + 1).ToString() + "/FI";
        t10 = (int.Parse(t.Substring(0, 2)) + 1).ToString() + "/SE";
        t11 = (int.Parse(t.Substring(0, 2)) + 1).ToString() + "/TH";
        t12 = (int.Parse(t.Substring(0, 2)) + 1).ToString() + "/FO";
        DropDownList1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(t1, ""));
        DropDownList1.Items.Insert(1, new ListItem(t2, ""));
        DropDownList1.Items.Insert(2, new ListItem(t3, ""));
        DropDownList1.Items.Insert(3, new ListItem(t4, ""));
        DropDownList1.Items.Insert(4, new ListItem(t5, ""));
        DropDownList1.Items.Insert(5, new ListItem(t6, ""));
        DropDownList1.Items.Insert(6, new ListItem(t7, ""));
        DropDownList1.Items.Insert(7, new ListItem(t8, ""));
        DropDownList1.Items.Insert(8, new ListItem(t9, ""));
        DropDownList1.Items.Insert(9, new ListItem(t10, ""));
        DropDownList1.Items.Insert(10, new ListItem(t11, ""));
        DropDownList1.Items.Insert(11, new ListItem(t12, ""));
        DropDownList1.SelectedIndex = 4;
    }
    else if (t.Contains("/SE"))
    {
        t1 = (int.Parse(t.Substring(0, 2)) - 1).ToString() + "/FI";
        t2 = (int.Parse(t.Substring(0, 2)) - 1).ToString() + "/SE";
        t3 = (int.Parse(t.Substring(0, 2)) - 1).ToString() + "/TH";
        t4 = (int.Parse(t.Substring(0, 2)) - 1).ToString() + "/FO";
        t5 = t.Substring(0, 2) + "/FI";
        t6 = t.Substring(0, 2) + "/SE";
        t7 = t.Substring(0, 2) + "/TH";
        t8 = t.Substring(0, 2) + "/FO";
        t9 = (int.Parse(t.Substring(0, 2)) + 1).ToString() + "/FI";
        t10 = (int.Parse(t.Substring(0, 2)) + 1).ToString() + "/SE";
        t11 = (int.Parse(t.Substring(0, 2)) + 1).ToString() + "/TH";
        t12 = (int.Parse(t.Substring(0, 2)) + 1).ToString() + "/FO";
        DropDownList1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(t1, ""));
        DropDownList1.Items.Insert(1, new ListItem(t2, ""));
        DropDownList1.Items.Insert(2, new ListItem(t3, ""));
        DropDownList1.Items.Insert(3, new ListItem(t4, ""));
        DropDownList1.Items.Insert(4, new ListItem(t5, ""));
        DropDownList1.Items.Insert(5, new ListItem(t6, ""));
        DropDownList1.Items.Insert(6, new ListItem(t7, ""));
        DropDownList1.Items.Insert(7, new ListItem(t8, ""));
        DropDownList1.Items.Insert(8, new ListItem(t9, ""));
        DropDownList1.Items.Insert(9, new ListItem(t10, ""));
        DropDownList1.Items.Insert(10, new ListItem(t11, ""));
        DropDownList1.Items.Insert(11, new ListItem(t12, ""));
        DropDownList1.SelectedIndex = 5;
    }
    else if (t.Contains("/TH"))
    {
        t1 = (int.Parse(t.Substring(0, 2)) - 1).ToString() + "/FI";
        t2 = (int.Parse(t.Substring(0, 2)) - 1).ToString() + "/SE";
        t3 = (int.Parse(t.Substring(0, 2)) - 1).ToString() + "/TH";
        t4 = (int.Parse(t.Substring(0, 2)) - 1).ToString() + "/FO";
        t5 = t.Substring(0, 2) + "/FI";
        t6 = t.Substring(0, 2) + "/SE";
        t7 = t.Substring(0, 2) + "/TH";
        t8 = t.Substring(0, 2) + "/FO";
        t9 = (int.Parse(t.Substring(0, 2)) + 1).ToString() + "/FI";
        t10 = (int.Parse(t.Substring(0, 2)) + 1).ToString() + "/SE";
        t11 = (int.Parse(t.Substring(0, 2)) + 1).ToString() + "/TH";
        t12 = (int.Parse(t.Substring(0, 2)) + 1).ToString() + "/FO";
        DropDownList1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(t1, ""));
        DropDownList1.Items.Insert(1, new ListItem(t2, ""));
        DropDownList1.Items.Insert(2, new ListItem(t3, ""));
        DropDownList1.Items.Insert(3, new ListItem(t4, ""));
        DropDownList1.Items.Insert(4, new ListItem(t5, ""));
        DropDownList1.Items.Insert(5, new ListItem(t6, ""));
        DropDownList1.Items.Insert(6, new ListItem(t7, ""));
        DropDownList1.Items.Insert(7, new ListItem(t8, ""));
        DropDownList1.Items.Insert(8, new ListItem(t9, ""));
        DropDownList1.Items.Insert(9, new ListItem(t10, ""));
        DropDownList1.Items.Insert(10, new ListItem(t11, ""));
        DropDownList1.Items.Insert(11, new ListItem(t12, ""));
        DropDownList1.SelectedIndex = 6;
    }
    else if (t.Contains("/FO"))
    {
        t1 = (int.Parse(t.Substring(0, 2)) - 1).ToString() + "/FI";
        t2 = (int.Parse(t.Substring(0, 2)) - 1).ToString() + "/SE";
        t3 = (int.Parse(t.Substring(0, 2)) - 1).ToString() + "/TH";
        t4 = (int.Parse(t.Substring(0, 2)) - 1).ToString() + "/FO";
        t5 = t.Substring(0, 2) + "/FI";
        t6 = t.Substring(0, 2) + "/SE";
        t7 = t.Substring(0, 2) + "/TH";
        t8 = t.Substring(0, 2) + "/FO";
        t9 = (int.Parse(t.Substring(0, 2)) + 1).ToString() + "/FI";
        t10 = (int.Parse(t.Substring(0, 2)) + 1).ToString() + "/SE";
        t11 = (int.Parse(t.Substring(0, 2)) + 1).ToString() + "/TH";
        t12 = (int.Parse(t.Substring(0, 2)) + 1).ToString() + "/FO";
        DropDownList1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(t1, ""));
        DropDownList1.Items.Insert(1, new ListItem(t2, ""));
        DropDownList1.Items.Insert(2, new ListItem(t3, ""));
        DropDownList1.Items.Insert(3, new ListItem(t4, ""));
        DropDownList1.Items.Insert(4, new ListItem(t5, ""));
        DropDownList1.Items.Insert(5, new ListItem(t6, ""));
        DropDownList1.Items.Insert(6, new ListItem(t7, ""));
        DropDownList1.Items.Insert(7, new ListItem(t8, ""));
        DropDownList1.Items.Insert(8, new ListItem(t9, ""));
        DropDownList1.Items.Insert(9, new ListItem(t10, ""));
        DropDownList1.Items.Insert(10, new ListItem(t11, ""));
        DropDownList1.Items.Insert(11, new ListItem(t12, ""));
        DropDownList1.SelectedIndex = 7;
    }
}
```

Any suggestions?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `""` (`string.Empty`) to the `ListItem` constructor:

```
DropDownList1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(t1, ""));
```

The DropDownList has to have valid values set (not just the text displayed in the list in the browser). This is done through the `DataValueField` property. Each value must be unique, otherwise you will end up in your situation where only the first (duplicate) would be selected.

Check the HTML source in your browser, you should have:

```
<select>
    <option value="some_unique_value1">text1</option>
    <option value="some_unique_value2">text2</option>
</select>
```

You need those unique values, as they are used for selecting the right item on the server.

Have you tried changing the constructor to pass it some unique values?  Change `""` to `Guid.NewGuid()` or something for testing.